# MySQL performance and speed

Tags: mysql

I'm having some problems with our MySQL server. Our system processes XML files from multiple sources and serve them online with a website and an API.

Our system has 40 CPUs and 256 GB of ram. At some points, all CPUs appear to be close to their limit (80%+), and our site starts to work slow and give a lot of errors.

We did a lot of stuff but we are unable to identify the problem, I hired a lot of IT resources to see if they could see whats happening but we are unable to identify the problem, any suggestion or advice would be a lot appreciated!

page error:

[This error occurs just sometimes when server is full on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1JrD.png)

htop image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4p7M.jpg)

all help would be appreciated

Comment: Those issues in the first image are coding errors. As for the htop, it looks unbelievable that such a db machine is knocked out by "processing XML files from multiple sources and serving it online by the website and an API". Probably bad coding + bad sysadmin. Unless you have 1M page views per day.

Answer (score 0):

scores.php software is pointed to as the source of your troubles.

According to the error message, you have Undefined property: in scores.php on line 53.  With no error handler.  This was after trying to get property on line 41 of same scores.php module.

Posting within your original question

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

would allow confirmation of reasonable values for timeouts,

```
innodb_print_all_deadlocks
innodb_io_capacity
innodb_io_capacity_max
```

and other aspects of your configuration.

Comment: Sorry..i think i was not clear, this error happends just some times and in some other pages also! this happends (looks like) no connection available at that time. but then on reload all looks perfect again